# Bootstrap3 background image not fit in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a small problem whit background image, I want to put it as a background for mine central div, see the picture:
[image]

Picture needs to fit in the div so text can display in the center of the image, its a simple stuff but for some reason mine image not fitting the div, can someone explain what is going on and tell me how can I overcome this.

Code for the background image:

```
.central_text{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background: url(../img/circle/new11.png);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is an [jsfiddle](http:////jsfiddle.net/k7yxtpc7/3/) working example of this image.

I have used `background:url(../img/circle/new11.png) center center no-repeat;` and this will center mine image, but that only display a part of it not the whole image. So I got this:
[image: After background code]

And I want to make it like this:
[image]

Comment: Try this `background-position: center;`

Comment: It's works, but still it is not fitting the div, it remained small

Comment: Then instead of `cover` use `background-size: contain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7yxtpc7/4/)

CSS:

```
.central_text{
 background:url(../img/circle/new11.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It's good, except it is only displaying a part of the image, need to display all of it.